# One Content Type - 2 Different Displays

Tags: users, display-suite, nodes, entities

I have a content type that I want to have certain fields show up for different users. For instance, for admin, I'd like the users to see all of the fields available, however, for non admins, I'd like to have one certain fields displayed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Field visibility & access can be controlled with the [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Field Permission is best choice. If you don't want to go with **Field Permission**  module then below is another option.
       function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

```
if($form_id == 'form_id') {
  global $user;

 //  print_r($user->roles);
 // Check to see if $user has does not have the administrator role.

  if (!in_array('anonymous user', array_values($user->roles))) {
    $form['field_your_field']['#access'] = FALSE;
      }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You may make two templates for that, one for admin user and second for non-admin user. In your custom templates you can show up fields according to your own will. For more details about template suggestion check [drupal docs](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656).